# How to get proposed time using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

When the other person declined the meeting and proposed a new time. In Outlook, you can see the proposed time.

[image]

Now I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API to get that proposed time.

For example, the original meeting date is **2018-03-08**, and the other person declined and proposed a new date **2018-03-12**.

I tried

```
GET /beta/me/messages/{messageId}=?$expand=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event
```

However, I cannot find the proposed time from the result returned. How can I get it? Thanks

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('576552d5-3bc0-42a6-a53d-bfceb405db23')/messages/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessage",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"DAAAABYAAACpTc/InBsuTYwTUBb+VIb4AADoRAyI\"",
    "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEMAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AADnwc8mAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2018-03-06T22:29:10Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-06T22:29:11Z",
    "changeKey": "DAAAABYAAACpTc/InBsuTYwTUBb+VIb4AADoRAyI",
    "categories": [],
    "receivedDateTime": "2018-03-06T22:29:11Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2018-03-06T22:29:05Z",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "internetMessageId": "<MWHPR15MB18399806CC97C61817C9A2B18BD90@MWHPR15MB1839.namprd15.prod.outlook.com>",
    "subject": "New Time Proposed: Test",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "parentFolderId": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAuAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhAQCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEMAAA=",
    "conversationId": "AAQkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgAQAOnuCMgoRLdGs-1scw6i7EU=",
    "conversationIndex": "AdO1mnWL6e4IyChEt0az/WxzDqLsRQAABO5D",
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": false,
    "isDraft": false,
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk%2FiwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc%2FInBsuTYwTUBb%2BVIb4AAAAAAEMAACpTc%2FInBsuTYwTUBb%2BVIb4AADnwc8mAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
    "inferenceClassification": "focused",
    "unsubscribeData": [],
    "unsubscribeEnabled": false,
    "meetingMessageType": "meetingDeclined",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "isOutOfDate": false,
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isDelegated": false,
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "Hi"
    },
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Rose",
            "address": "rose@example.com"
        }
    },
    "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Rose",
            "address": "rose@example.com"
        }
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Jack",
                "address": "jack@example.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [],
    "bccRecipients": [],
    "replyTo": [],
    "mentionsPreview": null,
    "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
    },
    "startDateTime": {
        "dateTime": "2018-03-08T04:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "endDateTime": {
        "dateTime": "2018-03-08T05:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Test",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueIdType": "unknown"
    },
    "recurrence": null,
    "event@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('576552d5-3bc0-42a6-a53d-bfceb405db23')/messages('AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEMAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AADnwc8mAAA%3D')/microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event/$entity",
    "event": {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"qU3PyJwbLk2ME1AW/lSG+AAA6EQMeA==\"",
        "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAENAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AADnwkmiAAA=",
        "createdDateTime": "2018-03-06T22:28:32.3852279Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-03-06T22:29:11.4604154Z",
        "changeKey": "qU3PyJwbLk2ME1AW/lSG+AAA6EQMeA==",
        "categories": [],
        "originalStartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
        "originalEndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
        "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000310000007643616C2D5569640100000033324633333433392D433744452D344338362D393046452D44424639314131363444323900",
        "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
        "isReminderOn": true,
        "hasAttachments": false,
        "subject": "Test",
        "bodyPreview": "Test",
        "importance": "normal",
        "sensitivity": "normal",
        "isAllDay": false,
        "isCancelled": false,
        "isOrganizer": true,
        "responseRequested": true,
        "seriesMasterId": null,
        "showAs": "busy",
        "type": "singleInstance",
        "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk%2FiwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc%2FInBsuTYwTUBb%2BVIb4AAAAAAENAACpTc%2FInBsuTYwTUBb%2BVIb4AADnwkmiAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
        "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
        "responseStatus": {
            "response": "organizer",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "Hi"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2018-03-08T04:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2018-03-08T05:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Test",
            "locationType": "default",
            "uniqueId": "Test",
            "uniqueIdType": "private"
        },
        "locations": [
            {
                "displayName": "Test",
                "locationType": "default",
                "uniqueId": "Test",
                "uniqueIdType": "private"
            }
        ],
        "recurrence": null,
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "declined",
                    "time": "2018-03-06T22:29:05Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Rose",
                    "address": "rose@example.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "organizer": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Jack",
                "address": "jack@example.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't expose this information directly. The related entities just don't have the fields defined to show this information. However, the data is obviously there, you just need to know how to get to it. The answer lies in [extended properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview).

Basically since Graph doesn't expose these values, we need to dig into the MAPI properties that store this data. After a little digging through the Exchange server protocol docs I found [PidLidAppointmentProposedStartWhole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee201243(v=exchg.80).aspx) and [PidLidAppointmentProposedEndWhole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159429(v=exchg.80).aspx). We just need to translate those MAPI property definitions into the Graph extended property syntax.

From the doc, those are both in the `PSETID_Appointment` namespace, which uses the GUID `{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`. `PidLidAppointmentProposedStartWhole` uses id 0x8250, and `PidLidAppointmentProposedEndWhole` uses id 0x8251. So those should translate to:

- `PidLidAppointmentProposedStartWhole`: `'SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8250'`
- `PidLidAppointmentProposedEndWhole`: `'SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8251'`

If we use those in an `$expand` clause as per [Get singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get), we get something like:

`GET /me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8250' or id eq 'SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8251')`

And the response looks something like this (other properties omitted):

```
{
    "subject": "New Time Proposed: Let's meet",
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id": "SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8250",
            "value": "2018-03-20T20:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "SystemTime {00062002-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8251",
            "value": "2018-03-20T21:00:00Z"
        }
    ]
}
```